# How to translate Presta Shop 1.6 when the string does not appear in backoffice?

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-modules

I have a PrestaShop 1.6 website and i've translated everything to SPANISH and downloaded the lagnguage packs but 4 items remain untranslated. I've search for them in backoffice and they are just not there. I found one, "Viewed Product", and the translation was empty so I proceed to fill it with the desired translation in Spanish, but it just doesn't work.

This are the strings that I cannot find a way to translate: [screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hntsq.png), [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dcsxZ.png), [screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VdR9D.png).

Have anyone encountered this issue before?

Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 0):

These translation have to been altered in the modules and cannot be found in the Theme files.

**Prestashop 1.6:**

Backoffice > Localization > Translations

[image]

For example the "Information" can be found in the Module **blockcms**